# How To Capture Last External Website Visited With Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, http-referer, referer

We're using Laravel as our login site, and when someone visits an endpoint to log out, we'd like to redirect them back to where they came from.

The problem is, the page they arrived from is not necessarily hosted on Laravel - it serves as a login site for multiple places - so we can't use the back() function because that only returns URLs from the Laravel site itself.

Basically, what I'd like to do is call PHP's $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] to see where they came from - but that appears to be blank no matter what browser I use.  Things that also don't work:

- $request->headers->get('referer');
- $request->server('HTTP_REFERER');
- url()->previous();
- url.intended

So what WOULD work?

Comment: If you have control over the site they come from you could simply add the referrer as an URL parameter, and store it for later use.

Comment: Have you tried get `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` before the user logs out?

Comment: There doesn't have to be a referer set btw so you always need a fallback

Comment: @lagbox I do know, but unfortunately never getting any indicates I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: @GeorgeMylonas Unfortunately, yes; that's mentioned in the post.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's $request->header('referer') in 5.8.

Though as always, never trust a referer.  They're easily spoofed.